# How can I speed up HTML manipulation via Javascript, and/or improve rendering speed of animations?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm having some trouble with rendering speed on a page with a lot of animated elements. There's a large `<table>` (about 500 rows), and a bit of JavaScript that reads updated html via SSEs and replaces the existing row contents with the updates. If I let the backend run at full speed, the browser (Chrome or WebKitGtk+) absolutely chokes, so I have it throttled down to about 100 updates per second. At this rate the page updates, but the frame rate is very low and the animations are jerky.

The performance seems to be much more sensitive to the number of rows in the table than to the update rate. For example, if I halve the number of rows in the table, the animations are much smoother than if I halve the update rate.

Looking at Chrome's timeline for a typical frame render, I see a bunch of calls to my EventSource 'message' listener, in parallel with HTML parsing and DOM manipulation (about 280 ms), which seems about right, if slower than I would like. Then I see about 50 ms of "Recalculate Style", 113 ms of "Layout", 30 ms of "Update Layer Tree" and 30 ms of "Paint", all executing serially, i.e. without anything else happening concurrently.

While the page is updating, the CPU graph shows one core at 100%, while the others are essentially idle. So I'm guessing that WebKit is using a single thread to do layout and such, and that I'm overtaxing that thread.

The page structure is basically:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class='mainTable'>
            <table id='mainTable' style="width:100%">
                <thead><!-- header stuff --></thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- About 500 <tr>s -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script src='quotes/tickUpd.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Each of the ~500 `<tr>`s looks something like:

```
<tr id = 'IBM'>
    <td class='cond'>128</td>
    <td class='exch'>*</td>
    <td class='size'>1</td>
    <td class='tickDown'>88.53<img class='arrow' src='quotes/DnArrow.png'/></td>
    <td class='symb'>GPC</td>
    <td class='tickDown'>102.66<img class='arrow' src='quotes/DnArrow.png'/></td>
    <td class='size'>1</td>
    <td class='exch'>*</td>
    <td class='time'>02:13:24.455186</td>
</tr>
```

The id of the `<tr>` is used to find the row, and the update contains just a series of `<td>`s. The `<td>`s with class 'tickDown' often change randomly between that and 'tickUp', while the `<img>` changes between 'DnArrow' and 'UpArrow' (the data represents stock price movements). The other classes remain the same.

The relevant styles are:

```
div.mainTable { width: 100%; font-size: 12px; columns: 32em; }

.symb { color: red; text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba( 0, 0, 0, .6 ); }

@keyframes greenToBlack { from { background-color: #69BE28; } }

.tickUp { animation: greenToBlack 2s;color: white; }

@keyframes redToBlack { from { background-color: red; } }

.tickDown { animation: redToBlack 2s; color: white; }

@keyframes greenToRed { from { color: #69BE28; } to { color: red; } }

.symb { animation: greenToRed 30s; }

.arrow { vertical-align: middle; width: 5px; height: 5px; }
```

The JavaScript looks like

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded",
    function(event) {
        var rows = document.getElementById('mainTable').rows;
        new EventSource("/upd").addEventListener(
            'message',
            function(event) {
                var update = JSON.parse(event.data);
                var row = rows.namedItem(update.rowId);
                row.innerHTML = update.html;
                // Was previously: $("tr#"+update.rowId).html(update.html);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I realize I'm asking a lot from my humble browser, but is there anything I can do to make this more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you for sure, but one suggestion would be not to prerender rows. Try to update individual cells with their individual values, without relying on `.innerHTML`, by direct manipulation of `.textContent` and `.classList`. This should at least remove your HTML parsing and DOM construction costs, and may or may not help with your layout costs (not too sure here, would need to test, but if your cell sizing  is fixed it might not need to be recalculated as you're not changing any dimensions).